How to detect if a user opens an outlook Event (with js)?
I created an Outlook add-in to connect OUtlook with notion. When a user tag a specific appointment with a specific tag, it sends it to a notion database.
Now I want to know if it's possible to first detect when a user open an Outlook event (to run code when this event occurs). Secondly, I want to know if it's possible to display a message on the appointment UI box ? (something like "Do you want to tag this event ?")
enter image description here
For example, when my add-in detects in subject appointments terms like "Board_meeting", I want to display a message to my user.
I try LaunchEvent, Eventype but nothing only related with the fact to open an appointment. I found something like "item.open" in VBA but I only want to use JS/Typescript.
